# CYGWIN on windows 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, cygwin

we have configured CYGWIN on windows 2008R2 and the services are started when we try to connect from outside to the server it is giving the below error.

$ sftp 501226742@tnwp010457.psamer.ps.ge.com Connecting to tnwp010457.psamer.ps.ge.com... @ WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED! @ @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY! Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)! It is also possible that the RSA host key has just been changed. The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is 31:36:55:8f:eb:ba:5f:1a:20:5a:b6:6f:45:db:07:04. Please contact your system administrator. Add correct host key in /export/home/chettigo/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message. Offending key in /export/home/chettigo/.ssh/known_hosts:2 RSA host key for tnwp010457.psamer.ps.ge.com has changed and you have requested strict checking. Host key verification failed. Connection closed

Answer (score 0):

As stated at the end, the host key has changed. If you restarted the server or the SSH server for Cygwin, then it regenerates the server's key. You'll need to edit your `ssh_config` file to allow you to connect to it, and store the key. Once that's done, you can enable the strict checking again.

Comment: Could you please throw more light on what has to be done to avoid the error , like steps that i have to perform on windows 2008(where cygwin) is installed ?

Comment: @vikas he told you that you need to edit your ssh_config file. so the intelligent question you should be asking is HOW.  You can look for `StrictHostKeyChecking ` if it's set to yes then that's why. You could put it to no. Or you could rm the known_hosts file. You should find where these files are. look within c:\cygwin\home   include subdirectories in your search

Comment: @vikas and if you can't do that then look up how to search for a file in Windows. And when you have a problem don't just ask for instructions step by step. State exactly what you have done and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the entry (IP address or alias) out of the known_hosts file on the client machine usually in the /.ssh/known_hosts file